# Recording Selenium tests from a web application.

Tags: selenium

We have a web application written in Flex we'd are already testing using Selenium. If you were tasked with investigating some solution that allows a user to press a record button from within the application and actually record a Selenium test, where would you begin?

I guess you'd need to wrap the whole Flex element in some something that is able to intercept clicks as well as track input. Is that even possible?

Answer (score -1):

for this, You have to record this event using Autoit Recorder. After compiling Autoit script .exe file will be generated.
So you can test that part by executing this .exe file from selenium RC